# How to validate INI-File format in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, validation, syntax, ini

I want to validate the format (syntax check) of an INI file with Eclipse. I'd prefer the DLTK validator using a PHP script (just checking @parse_ini_file for the return value).

How can I setup this in Eclipse?

When I try to setup a script, it ignores my INI files, only checking *.php files on change.

Answer (score 1):

In the menu Window/Preferences, General/Content Types, Test/Configutation files, in the box "File associations:"

Check: `*.ini (locked)` Is present or not? If not add it in.

Then [Add DLTK validator](http://wiki.eclipse.org/DLTK_Validators_User_Guide#How_to_edit_validators) for PHP INI file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. There is no "DLTK validator" treenode at my preferences :( I already installed DLTK 4.0 nightly build, but it's not there. I have Eclipse 3.7.2, with additionally PDT 3.0 (PHP). Do you have any further idea?

Comment: You may have 'Dynamic Languages' tab below 'General' tab on left sidebar. Select validators from it. And add validator for it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its still not working. I added a test.php to where you said, which should be used for it, but it's never called (I'm logging any execution). So thanks for your answer, if it's possible to send you a reward (reputation score), I'd do it, but I can't accept the answer, because it didn't solve the issue (but I'm closer than before) :(